# Recognize Android version by JavaScript run in WebView (no useragent available)

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I have html+javascript application running in Android's WebView. Unfortunately **WebView overwrites useragent** information. Now I need to **recognize from JavaScript** if Android version **is lower or higher than Android 3.0**.

Even If I could distinguish Android 4.0 from older version it would be success. I cannot update Android webview app not to overwrite useragent.

I think that newer webviews use different engine, so perhaps it's possible to recognize somehow which engine there is and indirectly OS version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found solution myself:

http://whichbrowser.net/
http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html
http://jimbergman.net/webkit-version-in-android-version/

So, even when useragent is empty, version of browser is available in javascript **navigator** object. And WebKit newer than 534 means that there is Android 3.0 or newer.

Answer (score 1):

```
var android3orHigher = ("matchMedia" in window);
var android4orHigher = ("performance" in window);
```

See support from:

http://caniuse.com/#feat=matchmedia

http://caniuse.com/#feat=nav-timing

Comment: thanks, that's also proper solution, but I've found simpler one. Object navigator contains browser version information.